# Django Allauth - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.account.middleware' even when django-allauth is properly installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-allauth, django-settings

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.account.middleware'"

I keep getting this error in my django project even when django-allauth is all installed and setup???

I tried even reinstalling and changing my python to python3 but didn't change anything, can't figure out why all other imports are working but the MIDDLEWARE one...

Help pls?

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for youtube2blog2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.4.

For more information on this file, see

For the full list of settings and their values, see
"""

from pathlib import Path
import django
import os
import logging
import pyfiglet

import allauth

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'omegalul'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# CUSTOM CODE

# os.environ['FFMPEG_PATH'] = '/third-party/ffmpeg.exe'
# os.environ['FFPROBE_PATH'] = '/third-party/ffplay.exe'

OFFLINE_VERSION = False

def offline_version_setup(databases):
    if (OFFLINE_VERSION):

        # WRITE CODE TO REPLACE DATABASES DICT DATA FOR OFFLINE SETUP HERE

        return True
    return

banner_ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format("CHRIST IS KING ENTERPRISES")

logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print("\n - CURRENT DJANGO VERSION: " + str(django.get_version()))

print("\n - settings.py: Current logger level is " + str(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.debug('settings.py: Logger is working.\n\n')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    
]

'''

NEEDED SETUP FOR SOCIAL AUTH

REQUIRES DEVELOPER CREDENTIALS

ON PAUSE UNTIL MVP IS DONE

# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
    'apple': {
        
    }
    'discord' {

    }
}
'''
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'

#

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    # My Apps
    'yt2b2',
    'home',
    'dashboard',

    # Django Apps

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Downloaded Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'embed_video',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.discord',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # Downloaded Middleware
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'youtube2blog2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'youtube2blog2.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3', # <--------- OFFLINE VERSION

        # Consider masking these secret variables using a .env file to beef up your Django app's security. Besides, Vercel allows you to list your environment variables during deployment.
        
        #'URL' : 'postgresql://postgres:oibkk5LL9sI5dzY5PAnj@containers-us-west-128.railway.app:5968/railway',
        #'NAME' : 'railway',
        #'USER' : 'postgres',
        #'PASSWORD' : 'oibkk5LL9sI5dzY5PAnj',
        #'HOST' : 'containers-us-west-128.railway.app',
        #'PORT' : '5968'
    }
}

# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # the path in url

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# Default primary key field type

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Tried changing to python3, reinstalling django-allauth through pip, other stackoverflow solutions, shifting through allauth docs... Nothing worked until now

Update: removed https links because of spam filter

Error location:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

# Downloaded Middleware
'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
```

]

Comment: If this is a project that will be deployed, remove the SECRET KEY from your question

Comment: whoooooooooops!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The middleware is only present in the unreleased 0.56.0-dev, likely you are using 0.55.2 and following 0.56 documentation.

Comment: Is documentation for older versions still available? I'm getting a 404 from https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/0.55.0/installation.html.

Answer (score 9):

The culprit is the Middleware entry.

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
  ...
  # Add the account middleware:
  "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware", # remove this, which only used in v0.56+
  ...
```

For the installation documentation for v0.55: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/0.55.0/installation.html